# vsCode can't retrieve/deploy anything

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, lwc, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

Working with Salesforce, org is authorised, everything works fine until it doesn't and there's no error code or anything.

In the morning I retrieved a few files I had to change, 10 minutes later when I needed to retrieve another one, it kept "Running SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org" for a few minutes and failed. Then again and again, whether I deploy something or retrieve, it just fails.

Closed, waited for it to sync, refreshed all lwcs, still the same problem.

Comment: Been having the same issue this morning

Comment: Apparently it's a SF problem and they're trying to fix it, but it's been 2 days now.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a sfdx-cli issue. There is a known issue right now with the version 7.150.0 reported here: https://github.com/salesforcecli/status

My team was having issues with our CI pipeline, and our fix was to use an older version. Once we updated our CI tool to grab `https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/versions/7.149.1/3881a5a/sfdx-v7.149.1-3881a5a-linux-x64.tar.xz` extract the binary, and run the tool, our deploys started working successfully.

Check your local and CI tool with the `sfdx --version` command. If you are using the broken one, roll it back to the version that you need.

Comment: I got in touch with SF support and after 3 days everything is finally working. It was a performance degradation on our sandbox.